# Access self from another class in python

Tags: python

I'm doing the Thinkful Python course at the moment and I can't figure out how to use the self attribute of one class in another class.

```
class Bicycle(object):
    # Have a model name
    # Have a weight
    # Have a cost to produce
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
        pass


class BicycleShop(object):
    # Create a bicycle shop that has 6 different bicycle models in stock. The shop should charge its customers 20% over the cost of the bikes
    margin = 1.2
    # Have a name
    # Have an inventory of different bikes
    # Sell bikes with a margin over their cost
    # Can see a total of how much profit they have made
    def __init__(self, company_name, models):
        self.company_name = company_name
        self.models = models

    def bicycle_models(self):
        for model in self.models.keys():
            print(model)

    def bicycle_prices(self):
        for model, price in self.models.items():
            if price <= customer_1.budget:
                print("The {} is available for a price of ${:.2f}.".format(model, price * self.margin))


class Customer(object):
    # Have a name
    # Have a fund of money used to purchase the bike
    # Can buy and own a new bicycle
    def __init__(self, name, budget):
        self.name = name
        self.budget = budget

    def check_funds(self):
        return evans_cycles.bicycle_prices()



evans_cycles = BicycleShop("Evans Cycles", { "BMC Road Machine": 125, "Cannondale Synapse": 275, "Pinnacle Laterite": 450, "Fuji Transonic": 625, "Cervelo R2": 750, "Specialized Roubaix": 999 })
print("\nWe are {} Bicycle Shop. Please see our range of bikes, below.\n".format(evans_cycles.company_name))
evans_cycles.bicycle_models()

customer_1 = Customer('Stuart', 1000)
print("\nHello, I'm {} and my budget is ${}. What can I afford?\n".format(customer_1.name, customer_1.budget))

print(customer_1.check_funds())
```

Currently, I have hard coded in customer_1.budget into the bicycle_prices method and evans_cycles into the check_funds function. But I'm aware this is not the correct way to do it, but I can't figure out how to do it any other way.

What is the correct way to utilize attributes of one class in another? I have tried to use inheritance, but it didn't work, it would not accept my dictionary as a parameter I think.

Comment: One remark I have on your idea: "I have tried to use inheritance". Inheritance can be seen as an "is-a" relation. So for example you have a class Bicycle, that covers all basic behavior of a bicycle, but you want to implement some extra behavior for a specific type of bicycle, for example a mountain bike ("mountain bike *is a* bike"), you can create a MountainBike class that inherits the behavior of the Bicycle class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you design something you have to think about relations. So how is a customer related to a shop? Well, lets assume that each shop has customers and each customer has only one shop (does not have to be true, just as an example). In that case you would do

```
class BicycleShop:
    ...

class Customer:
    def __init__(self, shop):
        self.shop = shop
```

so now customer has a reference to the shop. Now you can expose `get_models()` function in the shop:

```
class BicycleShop:
    def get_models(self):
        return self.models
```

and finally `check_funds` on `Customer`:

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self, name, budget, shop):
        self.name = name
        self.shop = shop
        self.budget = budget

    def check_funds(self):
        models = self.shop.get_models()
        for model, price in models.items():
            if price <= self.budget:
                print("The {} is available for a price of ${:.2f}.".format(model, self.get_price(model)))
```

You also have to implement `def get_price(self, model)` method on `BicycleShop` because (again relations) the price depends not only on the model but on the shop as well. Then it would go like this:

```
evans_cycles = BicycleShop("Evans Cycles", { "BMC Road Machine": 125, "Cannondale Synapse": 275, "Pinnacle Laterite": 450, "Fuji Transonic": 625, "Cervelo R2": 750, "Specialized Roubaix": 999 })
print("\nWe are {} Bicycle Shop. Please see our range of bikes, below.\n".format(evans_cycles.company_name))

customer_1 = Customer('Stuart', 1000, evans_cycles)
customer_1.check_funds()
```